# change the position of the li

Tags: jquery, html, css, onclick, positioning

I want to change the position of the li in jquery
I have 3 list item

```
<li class="flex-active-slider">
<div class="node_id"><span>233</span></div>
 <ul>
  <li class="69"><img></li>
  <li class="233"><img></li>
  <li class="299"><img></li>
 </ul> 
</li>
<a href="#" class="flex-next">click<a>
```

onload second list item is in center as I expected. onload[1,2,3],on click I want to change the position of the list as [3,1,2] and next click [2,3,1] .I want to change the list as given above in click function

```
 $('.flex-next').click(function(){
  //want to change in jquery
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to be able to select the `ul` tag.

This is the main idea. You can customize it.

```js
$('.flex-next').click(function(){
  ul = $('#myUi');
  lis = $(ul).find('li');
  $(ul).html('');
  len = lis.length;
  $(ul).append(lis[--len]);
  for (i = 0; i< len; i++) {
   $(ul).append(lis[i]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <ul id="myUi">
  <li class="69">1</li>
  <li class="233">2</li>
  <li class="299">3</li>
 </ul> 
</li>
<a href="#" class="flex-next">click<a>
```

Comment: I have tried with five list item and need to swap only middle three its not working in that case.but fine for 3 item

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42382202/change-the-position-of-the-middle-3-li-item.I have posted one more question

Answer (score 1):

you can use detach on elements and then use append. like this:

```
var parent = $( "div.node_id ul" );
var elem1 = $( "li.69" );
var elem2 = $( "li.233" );
var elem3 = $( "li.299" );

$('.flex-next').click(function(){
    elem1.detach();
    elem2.detach();
    elem3.detach();

    parent.append(elem3);
    parent.append(elem1);
    parent.append(elem2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
var parent = $("div.node_id ul");
var elem1 = $("li.69");
var elem2 = $("li.233");
var elem3 = $("li.299");
$(".flex-next").click(function () {
  elem1.detach();
  elem2.detach();
  elem3.detach();
  parent.append(elem3);
  parent.append(elem1);
  parent.append(elem2);
});
```